# Mandatory field while creating new database record in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NEt MVC. I've been trying to create a new database record.

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {


        var model = new Maping();
        return View(model);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Customerservice/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="CustomerServiceMappingID")] Maping serviceToCreate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

                return View();

       var dc = new ServicesDataContext();
       String s = serviceToCreate.ServiceID.ToString();

       if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
           ModelState.AddModelError("ServiceID", "ServiceID is required!");

        dc.Mapings.InsertOnSubmit(serviceToCreate);
         dc.SubmitChanges();

       return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

So, what I need to do is I need ServiceID to become mandatory... I tried this with not much use. So, can u please help me out?

Also I need to send the customerID which is another column of the table back to Index method.

Answer (score 0):

If ServiceId is an integer it should automatically be required. Otherwise you can put this attribute on ServiceId in your model class.

```
[Required]
public string ServiceId {get;set;} //assuming you are using a string
```

Can you post your model?

Answer (score 0):

Two things ...

1)
You need to add the Is Null = false to your database model, so that when the DataContext tries to save the new record away, then it will either create a new ID if those attributes are set or you need to supply one.

2)
Add an Attribute to your Maping model that tells MVC about the error you are throwing in the Create Action.

```
[Required]
public int ServiceID // <- replace with the correct type.
```

if your Index Action is like this ...

```
public ActionResult Index(int customerID), then you can send it with the RedirectToAction.

new { customerId = /* insert ID here */ }
```

that I believe is the third parameter in that method call.

Comment: @bdparish - Integers in models are automatically required when using validation as there is no valid 'non value' for them. only nullable ints (int? or Nullable<int> ) arent